# BOOST ASIO multi-io_service RPC framework design RFC

Tags: c++, boost-asio, rpc, system-design

I am working on a RPC framework, I want to use a multi io_service design to decouple the `io_objects` that perform the IO (front-end) from the the threads that perform the RPC work (the back-end).

The front-end should be single threaded and the back-end should have a thread pool. I was considering a design to get the front-end and back-end to synchronise using a condition variables. However, it seems `boost::thread` and `boost::asio` do not comingle --i.e., it seems condition variable `async_wait` support is not available. I have a question open on this matter [here](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/#ConditionVariables).

It occured to me that `io_service::post()` might be used to synchronise the two io_service objects. I have attached a diagram below, I just want to know if I understand the `post` mechanism correctly, and weather this is a sensible implementation.

[image: rpc system implementation]

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you use "[a single `io_service` and a thread pool calling `io_service::run()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples.html#boost_asio.examples.http_server_3)"

Also I assume that your frond-end is single-threaded just to avoid a race condition writing from multiple threads to the same socket.

The same goal can be achieved using [`io_service::strand`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service__strand.html) ([tutorial](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tuttimer5.html)).Your front-end can be MT synchronized by `io_service::strand`. All `posts` from back-end to front-end (and handlers from front-end to front-end like `handle_connect` etc.) should be wrapped by `strand`, something like this:

back-end -> front-end:

```
io_service.post(front_end.strand.wrap(
    boost::bind(&Front_end::send_response, front_end_ptr)));
```

or front-end -> front-end:

```
socket.async_connect(endpoint, strand.wrap(
    boost::bind(&Front_end::handle_connect, shared_from_this(), 
    boost::asio::placeholders::error)));
```

And all posts from front-end to back-end shouldn't be wrapped by `strand`.

Comment: no, I have read the source code to most of the examples :D I mean a single threaded IO service for doing the networking IO, and a IO service with multiple threads performing the RPC's :D

Comment: why did you choose this design? any benefit?

Comment: A single thread can multiplex thousands of connected clients easily, as long as no operations with non-deterministic complexity are involved (such as hard disk IO). Since the application in question is a complex event processing engine the RPC calls generally write to disk. This is the first reason, secondly I want to unit test the RPC services, and removing asynchronous/socket-based IO simplifies this greatly.

Comment: what about two `io_services`s? the first one (front-end) is run in single thread, the second one (back-end) is run by multiple threads. front-end and back-end exchange tasks by calling `io_service::post()`, no need in `condition_variable` or any other explicit syncrhonization

Answer (score 1):

If you back-end is a thread pool calling any of the `io_service::run(), io_service::run_one(), io_service::poll(), io_service::poll_one()` functions and your handler(s) require access to shared resources then you still have to take care to lock those shared resources somehow in the handler's themselves.

Given the limited amount of information posted in the question, I would assume this would work fine given the caveat above.

However, when posting there is some measurable overhead for setting up the necessary completion ports and waiting -- overhead you could avoid using a different implementation of your back end "queue".

Without knowing the exact details of what you need to accomplish, I would suggest that you look into thread building blocks for [pipelines](http://threadingbuildingblocks.org/files/documentation/a00150.html) or perhaps more simply for a [concurrent queue](http://threadingbuildingblocks.org/files/documentation/a00134.html).