# boost asio semaphore-like solution

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, boost-asio, boost-thread

This question is follow up of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7787873/boost-asio-need-to-post-n-jobs-only-after-m-jobs-have-finished) question. Anyhow, this is the motivation - a bit of c/p from original question's comment:

I'd like to be able to post one group of jobs on multiple threads (**CalcFib** functions), and then when the jobs are over, another group of jobs (**CalcFib2** functions), also on multiple threads. This cycle loops many times(here is two), so I thought the best thing to do is to create `boost::asio::io_service` and create threads at the beginning of the loop, so I don't have to create & destroy threads every time the loop starts/ends.

I had created two `int` vars wrongly named semaphore_**, and decrement them in above mentioned functions. The code that waits for the job group to finish is plain `while` as seen below. The solution works, at least as I can see.

Is the wait using `while` really a way to go? What am I missing? Is there a better way to do this?

My code looks like this:

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/mutex.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <iostream>

boost::mutex global_stream_lock;
int semaphore_fib = 0;
int semaphore_fib2 = 0;

void WorkerThread( boost::shared_ptr< boost::asio::io_service > io_service)
{
    global_stream_lock.lock();
    std::cout << "[" << boost::this_thread::get_id()
        << "] Thread Start" << std::endl;
    global_stream_lock.unlock();

    io_service->run();

    global_stream_lock.lock();
    std::cout << "[" << boost::this_thread::get_id()
        << "] Thread Finish" << std::endl;
    global_stream_lock.unlock();
}

size_t fib( size_t n )
{
    if ( n <= 1 )
    {
        return n;
    }
    boost::this_thread::sleep( boost::posix_time::milliseconds( 1000 ) );
    return fib( n - 1 ) + fib( n - 2);
}

void CalcFib( size_t n )
{
    global_stream_lock.lock();
    std::cout << "[" << boost::this_thread::get_id()
        << "] Now calculating fib( " << n << " ) " << std::endl;
    global_stream_lock.unlock();

    size_t f = fib( n );

    global_stream_lock.lock();
    std::cout << "[" << boost::this_thread::get_id()
        << "] fib( " << n << " ) = " << f << std::endl;
    semaphore_fib = semaphore_fib-1;
    global_stream_lock.unlock();
}

void CalcFib2( size_t n )
{
    global_stream_lock.lock();
    std::cout << "\t\t[" << boost::this_thread::get_id()
        << "] Now calculating fib2( " << n << " ) " << std::endl;
    global_stream_lock.unlock();

    size_t f = fib( n );

    global_stream_lock.lock();
    std::cout << "\t\t[" << boost::this_thread::get_id()
        << "] fib2( " << n << " ) = " << f << std::endl;
    semaphore_fib2=semaphore_fib2-1;
    global_stream_lock.unlock();
}

int main( int argc, char * argv[] )
{
    boost::shared_ptr< boost::asio::io_service > io_service(
        new boost::asio::io_service
        );
    boost::shared_ptr< boost::asio::io_service::work > work(
        new boost::asio::io_service::work( *io_service )
        );
    boost::asio::io_service::strand strand( *io_service );

    global_stream_lock.lock();
    std::cout << "[" << boost::this_thread::get_id()
        << "] The program will exit when all work has finished."
        << std::endl;
    global_stream_lock.unlock();

    boost::thread_group worker_threads;
    for( int x = 0; x < 2; ++x )
    {
        worker_threads.create_thread( 
            boost::bind( &WorkerThread, io_service)
            );
    }
    for(int loop_no=0; loop_no<2; ++loop_no)
    {
        semaphore_fib=3;
        io_service->post( boost::bind( CalcFib, 5 ) );
        io_service->post( boost::bind( CalcFib, 4 ) );
        io_service->post( boost::bind( CalcFib, 3 ) );
        while(semaphore_fib>0)
        {
            // waiting
        }

        global_stream_lock.lock();
        std::cout << "[" << boost::this_thread::get_id()
            << "] ******* CalcFib group finished ********" << std::endl;
        global_stream_lock.unlock();

        semaphore_fib2=3;
        io_service->post( boost::bind( CalcFib2, 2 ) );
        io_service->post( boost::bind( CalcFib2, 1 ) );
        io_service->post( boost::bind( CalcFib2, 1 ) );
        while(semaphore_fib2>0)
        {
            // waiting
        }
        global_stream_lock.lock();
        std::cout << "[" << boost::this_thread::get_id()
            << "] ******* CalcFib2 group finished  ********" << std::endl;
        global_stream_lock.unlock();
    }
    work.reset();
    worker_threads.join_all();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved too many `if` statements in `while` loop in `main()`.

- Added the `boost::condition_variable cv;` and `boost::mutex mx;` as global variables
- Added `boost::lock_guard<boost::mutex> lk(mx);cv.notify_all();`
  at the end of `CalcFib` and `CalcFib2` functions
- Added `boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lk(mx); cv.wait(lk);`
  in every `while` loop

That way I had accomplished that the `if` statement in `while` loop gets executed only when `cv.notify_all()` executes.